# Matplotlib - Canvas doesn't redraw

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas, cartopy

I have an GUI created with Wxpython. In my Main GUI i show and hide some panels. Also i call a function in my Panel class "active" this should redraw an matplot with an Cartopy map and some coordinates everytime it is called with new Data from the Main class.

my problem is that the canvas isnt redrawing as expected. I used `self.ax.clear()` to clear my plot and `self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()` to redraw it. But after "active" is called from main the first time the canvas shows the same map everytime.

So how do i redraw my map correctly?

The parameter "d" which is passed to the Panel Class is working correctly and changes as expected. Also all Data from the DB is showing up correctly if i print it.

Here is my shortened code:

```
def OnTest(self, d):
    self.panel_one.Hide()
    self.panel_two.Hide()
    self.panel_three.Hide()
    self.panel_four.Hide()

    RedrawTest.PanelOne.active(self.panel_five, d)

    self.panel_five.Show()
    self.Layout()
```

And here the panel class:

```
import wx
import wx.adv
from wx import TextCtrl, EVT_TEXT_ENTER, TE_PROCESS_ENTER

import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnnotationBbox,OffsetImage

import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER

import sqlite3

class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)    

        mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 

        self.fig=plt.figure(figsize=(100, 20))      
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, 1, self.fig) 

        mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)           
        mainsizer.Add(self.canvas, 1)         

        self.SetSizer(mainsizer)
        self.Layout()  

        self.Show()

    def active(self, d):        
        conn = sqlite3.connect("Database.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('SELECT Coordinates from Test WHERE TestID = ?', (d,))        
        coordinates = c.fetchone()[0]

        item_coord = coordinates.split(',')

        location_lat, location_lon = float(item_coord[0]),float(item_coord[1])        

        self.ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
        self.ax.clear()

        self.ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, facecolor='#FAFAFA')
        self.ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, facecolor='#F0F0F0')
        self.ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE, alpha=.25)
        self.ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', alpha=.25)

        self.ax.set_extent([-150, 60, -25, 90])
        self.fig.tight_layout()

        self.ax.set_facecolor('#F0F0F0')

        self.ax.plot([location_lon], [location_lat],
                 color='green', linewidth=2, marker='o',
                 transform=ccrs.Geodetic(),
                 )
        self.ax.text(location_lon + 2, location_lat - 2, str(coordinates),
                 horizontalalignment='left', fontsize=16,
                 transform=ccrs.Geodetic()) 

        plt.gca().outline_patch.set_visible(False)         

        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

        plt.close()
```